# Where the status of the system is stored when an android application is running?

Tags: java, android, debugging, logging, error-logging

i want to know where the status of the system like the memory usages, stack details, memory spaces, address spaces, etc.. of the system are stored when an android application is running and crashing. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the question is to know why your app is crashing, I suggest to just use http://fabric.io or the Crash Reporting section of https://console.firebase.google.com

Comment: no..i want to know where the whole status of the device are stored while the application is running and crashing..

Comment: I guess that it will be at the Java sandbox of that process. But I'm not a specialist about this, so I can't help too much. BTW, great question! I will share this question with my colleagues.